# google sign in in my flutter web app with firebase is not redirecting towards home page and only changes browser

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, web

It shows error as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hazQa.png)
my Auth functions are in this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eacyW.png)

I tried several hacks like I updated the dependencies also I added the sensitive scopes in OAuth consent screen in my firebase project and still it is not redirecting to home page it redirects to login instead
It changes the browser to my account but the screen it redireccts to is still the login screen what should I do I also changed the port to 5000[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXmOs.png)

Comment: does it still shows signin page after signing in and  hot reload?

Comment: Please describe your problem concisely and in simple way! What is the problem you're coming across?

Comment: attach error and code as a text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.